# Trouble implementing a class-based non-binary id3 decision solution

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, decision-tree

EDIT: I've added my own methods for entropy/inf gain/best split at the bottom in case anybody wants to help me debug so they don't have to write their own!

As a challenge, after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKD5gxPPeY0) I wanted to create a solution in Python (class based to practice OOP). Since the data here is categorical I wanted to create the tree so that it would be represented visually as similarly to the video (i.e. possibly >2 children, labels on split and values, etc.).

I have done my best to debug the code so that it runs. In its current state it has two huge problems:

(1) The instantiated class' list of children is showing some None values and some Tree objects. Since the None values break the .predict function, I have placed a temporary if statement to ignore them

(2) The value attributes show "Yes" and "No" which are target values rather than the feature values. e.g.

```
In: dt.tree_.children[0].value
Out: "Yes"
```

The feature splits aren't in the label attribute whatsoever. The label field is None regardless of node/child, and the prediction also returns None. I've gone over the code for hours but can't work out why. I've included the data (duplicated from the video) and DataFrame setup for ease of access and to show how I am attempting to run the program.

My apologies in advance for the very long post! I'm trying to explain my logic (and don't want people to think I'm just asking others to write my code) even though it will probably deter most people from helping!

Note: the decision tree class uses nested functions so that the .fit will always begin with a new instantiation of Tree() and so .predict will use the dt.tree_ attribute which should be populated after .fit

Tree() class:

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, children = [], label = None, value = None):
        self.children = children    #used in place of left and right for binary solutions
        self.label = label          #to label which feature this node's children are split on
        self.value = value          #the values of the above node's split feature. This should always be None for the head node
```

Pseudocode for dt.fit:

```
def fit(self, data, target, features)
    def run_id3(data, target, features, tree):

        (base case)
        Check if target column has only one unique value. 
            If so, set current tree label to target column, add one child below current tree with target value
            return (end recursion)

        find the best feature to split data on
        set current node label to feature
        for each unique value in splitting feature:
            create a node and set value equal to unique value
            append new node to the children list of the current tree
            recur with data filtered for the current unique feature value (split) and with the child tree as the head
    run_id3(data, target, features, self.tree_)
```

Code for dt.fit:

```
class DecisionTree():
    tree_: Tree

    def __init__(self):
        self.tree_ = Tree()
        pass

    def fit(self, data, target, features):
        def run_id3(data, target, features, tree):
            unique_targets = pd.unique(data[target])
            if len(unique_targets) == 1:
                tree.label = target
                tree.children.append(Tree(value=unique_targets[0]))
                return
            best_split = find_best(data, target, features)
            tree.label = best_split
            for unique_val in np.unique(data[best_split]):
                new_tree = Tree()
                new_tree.value = unique_val
                tree.children.append(run_id3(data[data[best_split] == unique_val], target, features, new_tree))

        run_id3(data, target, features, self.tree_)
```

Pseudocode for dt.predict:

```
def predict(self, row):
    def get_prediction(tree, row):
        check if current node has no children
            return node label (should be target prediction)
        set current column (feature split) to current node label
        for each child of current node
            if child is not null (THIS IS NOT GOOD, EXISTS TO STOP PROGRAM HALTING)
                if child’s value is equal to the value in that column in our test row
                    recur (go down tree), set current child tree to head in parameter

    tree = self.tree_ (so tree starts at the head of the instantiated tree, should be populated after dt.fit)
    return get_prediction(tree, row)
```

Code for dt.predict:

```
    def predict(self, row):
        def get_prediction(tree, row):
            if len(tree.children) == 0:
                return tree.label
            column = tree.label
            for child in tree.children:
# the below conditional is purely to stop the program halting since I haven't worked out why the children attribute keeps adding NoneType objects
                if child is not None:
                    if child.value == row[column]:
                        return get_prediction(child, row)

        tree = self.tree_
        return get_prediction(tree, row)
```

Data setup:

```
outlook = ['Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Overcast', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Overcast', 'Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Rain', 'Sunny', 'Overcast', 'Overcast', 'Rain', 'Rain']
humidity = ['High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'High', 'Normal', 'High', 'High']
wind = ['Weak', 'Strong', 'Weak', 'Weak', 'Weak', 'Strong', 'Strong', 'Weak', 'Weak', 'Weak', 'Strong', 'Strong', 'Weak', 'Strong', 'Weak']
play = ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', '?']

columns = ["Outlook", "Humidity", "Wind", "Play"]
data = pd.DataFrame([outlook, humidity, wind, play]).T
data.columns = columns
train = data.iloc[:-1, :]
test = data.iloc[-1, :3]
features = columns.copy()
features.remove("Play")
target = "Play"

dt = DecisionTree()
dt.fit(train, target, features)
pred = dt.predict(test)
```

Information gain methods:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



def entropy(column):
    elements, counts = np.unique(column, return_counts=True)
    # if statement in comprehension stops nan result since 0*log2(x) is undefined, returns 0. in this case,
    # 1*log2(1) + 0*log2(0) = 0. zero entropy result, zero uncertainty is consistent with theory
    entropy = np.sum(
        [-(counts[i] / np.sum(counts)) * np.log2(counts[i] / np.sum(counts)) if counts[i] > 0 else 0 for i in
         range(len(counts))])
    return entropy


def information_gain(data, split_name, target_name):
    target_entropy = entropy(data[target_name])
    vals, counts = np.unique(data[split_name], return_counts=True)
    weighted_entropy = np.sum(
        [counts[i] / np.sum(counts) * entropy(data.loc[data[split_name] == vals[i], target_name]) for i in
         range(len(counts))])
    return target_entropy - weighted_entropy


def find_best(data, target_name, features):
    max_gain = 0
    best_col = ""
    for col in features:
        gain = information_gain(data, col, target_name)
        if gain > max_gain:
            max_gain = gain
            best_col = col
    return best_col
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't provide a complete answer, but I'll make these observations:

In `DecisionTree.fit`, inside the `run_id3` function, you append to `tree.children` twice, one of these append calls must be the cause of the `None` values in child nodes.

This one looks ok, you're appending a tree:

```
tree.children.append(Tree(value=unique_targets[0]))
```

This one looks more suspicious:

```
        for unique_val in np.unique(data[best_split]):
            new_tree = Tree()
            new_tree.value = unique_val
            tree.children.append(run_id3(data[data[best_split] == unique_val], target, features, new_tree))
```

You're appending the return value of `run_id3` to the `tree.children`, but `run_id3` doesn't return a value, and in Python functions that do not return a value return  `None`. `run_id3` appends to the children list of the tree that's been passed to it, so your code should *probably* be this:

```
        for unique_val in np.unique(data[best_split]):
            new_tree = Tree()
            new_tree.value = unique_val
            run_id3(data[data[best_split] == unique_val], target, features, new_tree)
```

A couple of minor style points:

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, children = [], label = None, value = None):
        self.children = children
```

You don't need the brackets after `Tree`, unless you want to inherit from another class, in which case you would have `class Tree(Ancestor):...`

Providing [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) in function parameters such as `children=[]` can have unexpected effects, so it's best to avoid this practice. Use this idiom instead:

```
class Tree: 

    def __init__(self, children=None, label=None, value=None):
        self.children = children if children is not None else []
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on the code and the stylepoints! Moving from Java I'm still getting the hang of Python OOP. I'll implement the logic changes tomorrow and edit this comment with the results!

Comment: Update: Your suggestions helped and I cleaned the code a bit! There was also an error in my prediction return logic. The leaf in .fit stored the prediction in the value attribute but I was searching for when there was no children and returning the label attribute. I changed it to search for when 1 child is present, and returned that child's value. I also had significant trouble until I restarted the session clearing the namespace. To avoid this in future, I have defined the initial tree attribute within the outer fit function so the tree is always a new instantiation! Thanks again.